# Error when running cucumber with java/IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber

I've set up cucumber with Java in intelliJ, and I've just glued my feature file to my steps file and tried to run it. It's not really testing anything - it should pass. But I'm getting this warning/error. I'm learning by tutorial and I've followed the steps exactly so can't understand why this is happening? Can anyone help? Error is below:

```
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/C:/Users/Kristian.Senior/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps/1.0.6/cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.6.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

    Skipped step

    Skipped step

    Skipped step

    Skipped step

    1 Scenarios (1 pending)
    4 Steps (3 skipped, 1 pending)
    0m0.393s

    cucumber.api.PendingException: TODO: implement me
        at Steps.LoginFeature.iNavigateToTheLoginPage(LoginFeature.java:18)
        at ✽.I navigate to the login page(C:/Users/Kristian.Senior/CucumberBasics/src/test/java/Features/login.feature:6)
```

Comment: You should implement "step".

Comment: can you give me an example? Not sure what you mean

Comment: ah wait I see. I've given the steps actions but the test still doesn't pass?

Comment: @When("Step")
public void step() {
    //implementation
}

Comment: It says in the stack trace. Implement step "I navigate to login page"

Comment: yes thank you I have it figured out

Comment: I was assuming it would pass before adding any implementation

Comment: That depends on the Cucumber Options. Read about "strict" :)

Comment: thanks! I have another question if you can help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190294/discussion-between-fenio-and-golf-umbrella).

Comment: i've added the implementations, a system.out.println() for each step, but when it prints in the console, it prints along one line, it doesn't begin a new line for each step? do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the exception

```
cucumber.api.PendingException: TODO: implement me
        at Steps.LoginFeature.iNavigateToTheLoginPage(LoginFeature.java:18)
        at ✽.I navigate to the login page(C:/Users/Kristian.Senior/CucumberBasics/src/test/java/Features/login.feature:6)
```

which enforces you to implement the step described in the exception.

Implement step like this:

```
@When("I navigate to the login")
public void i_navigate_to_the_login() {
    System.out.printf("Navigating to login\n");
}
```

In order to just skip those steps you can set `strict` option in `CucumberOptions`

> Strict: if the strict option is set to false then at execution time if
>   cucumber encounters any undefined/pending steps then cucumber does not
>   fail the execution and undefined steps are skipped and BUILD is
>   SUCCESSFUL.

Comment: `strict`-mode was removed in Cucumber 7 [release-notes](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/release-notes/v7.0.0.md#strict-mode-and-non-strict-mode-options-have-been-removed)